# Strange rendering error in SL app... out of browser issue?

Tags: silverlight

I've been working on a SL5 app for a few days. I've mostly been using a hard coded dummy data collection when styling my app's view. Everything has been working fine, but now I want to connect it to a dynamic data collection generated by my view model (using the data service technique where you have design time & real data depending on the IsInDesignTool property.

After I cleared out the control of the hard coded data and bound it to a collection in my view model. When I run it in debug mode, I see an unhandled exception being thrown in App.xaml.cs. The exception args don't say exactly what the problem is (it is simply saying "Value does not fall within the expected range" but when I look at the sender I find the following coming from the MainWindow (my app only has a single view): "Out-of-browser specific settings do not affect in-browser applications."

Further, when I try to view the MainWindow in the designer in VS, it doesn't render and instead shows an error (the rendered exception in the designer doesn't have any of my namespaces in it, just things about controls & UIElements).

I'm at a bit of a loss how to troubleshoot this. I didn't set anything for out-of-browser when building the app and since it worked with dummy data collections, why would it suddenly have this issue (seems like if I was using an out-of-browser property it would have shown up before I bound the data to the view).

Tips/pointers?

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for my bad english)

I am not sure on what is happening but I saw the error `"Out-of-browser specific..."` when I tried to access some specific property only available to OOB while running on browser. The solution was to test if running oob before using the property:

```
if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

The other problem possibly is unrelated - and sometimes can be really hard to debug - one thing that helped me is to open another instance of VS and attach it to the one where you are seeing the problem. With this setup, go to your problematic View and change to "design view" - keep an eye on the Output window of the attached VS to see if some meaningful exception is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I did put a `Textbox` inside kind of `Listbox` (`radPanelBar`) and added

`HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` to the `Textbox`. It seems that the textbox had problems when to show the scrollbar and when not. Adding

`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` to the Listbox did solve it **(** so, no OOB issue at all **)**.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what the error was, but it wasn't at all realted to OOB. I'm using a data service approach (in design time I programatically build real data, not the Expression Blend sample data, but when not in a design tool, it uses the REST services). I started disabling a lot of things in my dynamic data and slowly added them back. Somewhere along the way my dummy data generation was fouling things up, but SL thought it was an OOB issue.